# Algorithm / challenge . I want to calculate all games

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have data/teams in mongodb. Each team has 11 items:

One object looks like this. I would like to calculate only games together.
But I have 8 objects! All games from obj1 + all games from obj2 + ...
All games from each obj together.

Can you find better solutions like obj1.game1 + obj1.game2 + ... obj2.game1 + ...

THANK YOU

```
_id: 'adsf...',
game1: 1,
game2: 2,
game3: 3,
game4: 4,
game5: 5,
game6: 6,
game7: 2,
name: 'xxx,
url: 'xxx',
city: 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all key-value pairs of the object and then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum up all the values that have a key starting with `game`.

> You could also use some regex if you want a more precise match of the property name and want to avoid matching something like `gameDay`.

```js
const obj1 = {
    _id: 'adsf...',
    game1: 1,
    game2: 2,
    game3: 3,
    game4: 4,
    game5: 5,
    game6: 6,
    game7: 2,
    name: 'xxx',
    url: 'xxx',
    city: 'xxx'
}

const gameTotal = Object.entries(obj1)
    .reduce((total, [key, value]) => key.startsWith("game") ? total += value : total, 0);
console.log(gameTotal);
```